# How to add opacity from 0 to 100 with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity

Animate the boxes to random position and then move them back to their original position but i have no idea how to add + opacity from 0 to 100 on this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();            
    $('#intro .box').each(function(){
        var originalOffset = $(this).position(),
            $this = $(this),
           tLeft = w-Math.floor(Math.random()*900),
           tTop  = h-Math.floor(Math.random()*900);

        $(this).css({
            "left": tLeft,
            "top": tTop
        });

        $this.animate({ "left": originalOffset.left, 
                         "top": originalOffset.top
                     },5000);

    });
});
```

so please help :)
here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HgMB4/24/

Comment: As opacity is set from 0 to 1, just divide your value with.... wait for it .... 100, to get the right value ?

Comment: What do you mean by "add opacity"?  I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: Possible duplicated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390361/jquery-opacity-animation

Comment: @BenBarden something like fade in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `.box` to `opacity: 0` in the CSS.

Then in your animate function, add opacity: 1 as one of the attributes.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hr5ZT/1/

```
    $this.animate({ "left": originalOffset.left, 
                     "top": originalOffset.top,
                   "opacity": 1
                 },5000);
```

Comment: @MirkoMukaetov If this is the thing that works, it is generally considered polite to accept it as your answer by clicking on the green check-mark next to it.