# How to animate the background opacity of an element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a picture as a background on my HTML tag and a background colour of rgba( 0,0,0, 0.7 ); on my BODY tag. I'm building a small script that will allow me to change the background image on the fly and to do this I would like to animate the body to be rgba( 0,0,0,1 ), change the image, and then animate back to the opacity of 0.7.

I've googled and found that a jQuery plugin called [jQuery Color](http://plugins.jquery.com/color/) but the plugin seems to be broken in the latest version of jQuery "b.end is undefined". Others who have asked a similar questions also have answered with comments saying that this solution no longer works.

I'm a little at a loss, all googling leads to the same plugin, does anyone else know of a solution?

Currently this is what I'm trying:

```
jQuery('body').animate({
    'backgroundColor':'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
});
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) can do this out of the box (so all you need is jQuery and jQuery UI).

You almost had it. Add the jQuery UI script call in the `head` after your jQuery script call (`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`) and then try this:

```
jQuery('body').animate({
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
});
```

`backgroundColor` is the jQuery property name, which does not need to be in quotes.  Quotes are only needed for CSS properties that have dissimilar corresponding jQuery property names, which would be `background-color` (the CSS property that `backgroundColor` stands for).  So this would also work:

```
jQuery('body').animate({
    'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
});
```

This can also be accomplished quite simply with pure CSS3 animations.

Comment: I'm so mad at myself, turns out I did not have the latest version of jquery ui and that the animate functionality was added after the fact. Thank you for confirming that this is in fact a UI functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't finished this code, but this is the basis for pure jQuery. It's a start to an idea for you.  Try something like this:

```
$('.background').click(function(){
    var changeColor;
    var speed = 100;
    var i = speed;
    changeColor = setInterval(function(){
        i--;
        var opacity = i / speed;
        $('.background').css({backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0, " + opacity + ")"});
    }, 1);
    setTimeout(function(speed){
        clearInterval(changeColor);
     }, speed * 5);

});
```

The basic principle is to change a number every 1ms which would then control a percentage that would act as a variable for your background color.  This is not efficient, but it's exactly the thought you're looking for.

**UPDATE** Check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mV4st/3/

Answer (score -1):

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390361/jquery-opacity-animation) you can find a way to do it:

```
$(document.body).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
```

Comment: Opacity would change the entire opacity of the entire div, not just the background color

Comment: You are rigth @ntgCleaner, looking for this a bit in google it seems like the easiest way to do it is using a plugin. [This](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) looks good and is very ligth.

Comment: Unfortunately that plugin is also old and doesn't seem to work with the version of jQuery I'm using (the latest).