# Jquery fade opacity to 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this script that does a few things but the focus is the last line as it doesn't seem to make the class opacity arrive at 100%....

```
$('.fa-briefcase').parent().on('click', function () {
      $("#colorscreen").remove();
      $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
      $("body").append('<div id="colorscreen" class="animated"></div>');
      $("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBig");
      $('.fadeInUpBig').css('background-color', 'rgba(33,29,134, 0.2)');
      $(".tile-area-main").css({width: "720px"}).load("content.html #overview");
      $(".submenu-ctn").load("content.html .submenu-ctn");
      $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');  
      $( ".submenu-ctn" ).animate({ opacity: 10 }, 2000);
});
```

the css of the class is this....

```
.metro .submenu-ctn {
    position: fixed;
    left: 3px;
    top: 150px;
    height:400px;
    width:263px;
    float:left;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index : 999;
    opacity:0;

}
```

does anyone know why the class .submenu-ctn isn't animating to 100% opacity within 2 seconds ?

EDIT ...

Since the issue is still causing issues I wanted to post the html of the pages (on request) that are being used here to help...

... fro the index.html page (where stuff is getting loaded to)

```
<!-- INITIALISE THE SPACE FOR CONTENT -->        
<div class="tile-area">
<!--INITIALISE THE DIVS FOR CONTENT TO BE LOADED INCLUDING SUBMENU OPTIONS -->
<div class="submenu-ctn"></div> 
<div class="tile-area-main"></div>
```

the content.html page that is having it's divs selectively loaded into the divs above...

```
<div class="submenu-ctn">

  <header class='masthead'>
  <div class='brand-container'>
    <a href='#'>
      <span class='brand-initials'>Who Are Musability?</span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-briefcase brand-initials-icon"></i></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class='nav-container'>
      <div>
      <a class='slide' href='#'>
          <span class='element'>Mission and Values</span>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a class='slide' href='#'>
          <span class='element'>Ethos</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
       <a class='slide' href='#'>
          <span class='element'>Music</span>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a class='slide' href='#'>
          <span class='element'>Expression</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a class='slide' href='#'>
          <span class='element'>People</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a class='slide' href='#'>
          <span class='element'>Potential</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it not changing it at all, or doing it instantly? Also you have `load("content.html .submenu-ctn");` are you trying to load in content.html and accidently put in the css class?

Comment: Possible duplicate: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390361/jquery-opacity-animation)

Comment: not changing it at all

Comment: Maybe try `$( ".metro .submenu-ctn" ).animate({ opacity: 10 }, 2000);`

Comment: good point trying now

Comment: nope , very very strange as soon as i give the css value opacity:0; it just doesn't appear

Comment: correct, opacity: 0 means the element will not be displayed

Comment: yeah but i have to set it to 0 so that i can use the jquery to get it to 1 what am i doing wrong here NightOwl ?

Comment: HAHAHAH --- we are all morons , ... the class being loaded into the class on the page are THE SAME NAME ... therefore it was getting confused... sorted the problem ... everyone gets a vote up regardless

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`opacity` property values are from `0, 0.1,0.2,0.3, etc, etc`  to 1 so 10 its invalid

change it to

```
$( ".submenu-ctn" ).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 2000);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/hihogozocu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: While the opacity wont reach a value of 10, it still can be used. The animation will just happen faster than if you used 1

Comment: do you think it has anything to do with it being loaded from another html file as per line 7 of the script ?

Comment: @havingagoatit, are you sure that you are pointing to the right element? console the result  of $( ".submenu-ctn" ) to see if you are using the right selector

Comment: yeah just checked it is being loaded fine from line 7 of the script , i took the opacity:0 out of the css and it is there

Comment: Then we will need more details like browser and jquery version and the html code

Comment: browser is latest firefox , jquery is 1.10.2 html on the way with an edit

Comment: HAHAHAH --- we are all morons , ... the class being loaded into the class on the page are THE SAME NAME ... therefore it was getting confused... sorted the problem ... everyone gets a vote up regardless –

Answer (score 1):

`opacity`’s initial value is `1`, so make sure to animate to `1`.

Here’s what the spec says about `opacity`: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency

Try this:

`$('.submenu-ctn').animate({
   opacity: 1
}, 2000);`

Here’s a jsbin to illustrate this: http://output.jsbin.com/lefilerube/2/

Also consider `fadeTo` since, according to jQuery’s docs, it should be used when you’d like to “adjust the opacity of the matched elements”.

With your example, that would translate to:

`$('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(2000, 1);`

Hope that helps.

Comment: it didn't work... I am beggining to think it is getting confused on which class to de-opacify through the use of the same class name on both html pages

Comment: HAHAHAH --- we are all morons , ... the class being loaded into the class on the page are THE SAME NAME ... therefore it was getting confused... sorted the problem ... everyone gets a vote up regardless –